# recursive method to how to count how many different numbers in array? [java]

Tags: java

I need to write a recursive function for counting how many different values in array, and the only values that can appear in it are `0-9`.

For example, for the following array:

```
{   { 1, 5, 4, 3 }, 
    { 4, 3, 2, 1 },     
    { 4, 5, 1, 4 },
    { 1, 4, 3, 2 }
};
```

The function will return `5` because the only values appearing in this array are: `1,2,3,4,5`

That's what I have tried so far I don't understand how to promote the index without using `for`

```
public static int numOfColors(int[][] map) { 
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int colors=0;
    int contains=map[i][j];
    if (map == null ) { 
        return 0;
    } else if (map[i][j] != 0&&map[i][j]!=contains) { 
        colors ++;
    }
    return numOfColors(map) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array like: int numbers[ ][ ], you can do something like

```
public int getNUnique(int[][] numbers) {
     int usedNumbers[10];
     boolean found=false;
     for(int i=0, i<numbers.lenght, i++) {
         for(int j=0, i<numbers[].lenght, j++) {
              for(int x=0, x<usedNumbers.lenght, X++) {
                   if(numbers[i][j]==usedNumbers[x]) {
                       found=true;
                   }
                   if(!found) {
                       usedNumbers[usedNumbers.lenght]=numbers[i][j];
                   }
              }
         }
         return usedNumbers.length
     }
```

Comment: that's not recursive

Comment: correct me if i wrong that's not a recursive way to solve this problem..

Comment: It's true, it isn't. But the other solutions are right, i just don't have enough reputation to vote them

Answer (score 0):

You need another parameter for the recursive call: that is a Set of Integers that you have already seen. Or you could use a BitSet, or even a string since you are restricted to single digits.

As for advancing the index, you could either pass in two parameters, representing row and column, or you could use a div(/) and mod (%) strategy to compute row and column from a single index parameter.

Finally, you might consider getting rid of the need for index altogether, by simply passing in an iterator instead of an array (although the idea of passing an iterator into a recursive call does seem odd):

```
public static int numColors(PrimitiveIterator.OfInt iter, BitSet seen) {
    if(!iter.hasNext())
        return seen.cardinality();
    seen.set(iter.nextInt());
    return numColors(iter, seen);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {
        { 1, 5, 4, 3 }, 
        { 4, 3, 2, 1 },     
        { 4, 5, 1, 4 },
        { 1, 4, 3, 2 }};
    PrimitiveIterator.OfInt iter  = Arrays.stream(arr).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).iterator();
    System.out.println(numColors(iter, new BitSet()));
}
```

And as requested, here is a more "stupid" approach:

```
public class SampleJava {
private static final int MAX_COLORS = 10;
public static int numColors(int[][] arr, int row, int column, int[] seen) {
    if(row == arr.length) // end of rows
        return 0; // done
    if(column == arr[row].length) // end of column
        return numColors(arr, row + 1, 0, seen); // advance to next row
    seen[arr[row][column]]++; // increment the "seen" count for this color 
    if(seen[arr[row][column]] == 1) // are we seeing a new color?
        return 1 + numColors(arr, row, column + 1, seen); // yes. next column
    return 0 + numColors(arr, row, column + 1, seen); // no. next column
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {
        { 1, 5, 4, 3 }, 
        { 4, 3, 2, 1 },     
        { 4, 5, 1, 4 },
        { 1, 4, 3, 2 }};
    System.out.println(numColors(arr, 0, 0, new int[MAX_COLORS]));
}
}
```

Comment: I did not learn yet all the things you used (bitset,ofint etc..) maybe there is more simple and "stupid" recursive way for this problem?

Comment: @MarkZikri yes, for example, `numColors(int[][] arr, int row, int column, Set<Integer> seen)` ... see my edit

Comment: i'm use eclipse and She did not recognize what is "set" and "hashset".. and i don't learn how to use it yet maybe just explain me the idea behind your progrem?

Comment: @MarkZikri wow you haven't learned about imports yet? You can't use a class like Set or HashSet unless it is imported. Eclipse can automatically fix your imports with this keyboard shortcut: `Ctrl + Shift + O` ... as for your other question, the explanation is provided by the comments on each line of the program

Comment: @MarkZikri I have updated my "stupid" method so that it doesn't use any imports now (array instead of Set). Please remember to accept the answer which is correct. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkZikri why are you posting a wrong answer as a comment to my correct answer? It is possible to solve the problem in many ways. Accept the answer then if you have a new question, post a new question. Completely communicate your requirements and intentions.

Answer (score 0):

As other people suggested, you need an out of scope element, whose life cycle is independent of the recursive function you are using, to keep the colors (numbers) you visited.